# OPC Server gives 0x80070005 (Access is denied) error to OPC client not running as Administrator

Tags: security, com, dcom, opc

I have developed an OPC DA server which runs as a windows service. When I try to connect to it OPC client it gives me 0x80070005 (Access is denied) error. However if I run the client as administrator it connects properly. This is a problem since I cannot force clients to run in admin mode. What is the solution to this problem? I tried setting DCOM properties using DCOM config but haven't succeeded.

Comment: Try defining a specific user account under which the service is running. Use the same user account that you wish to run the client.

Comment: @JouniAro can you specify the steps?

Comment: Open the Services application - find your service - select Properties - select Log In tab and define the user account.